# Changing Windows/CIFS NAS Share/Storage Level Permissions Recursively

Tags: windows, network-attached-storage

**"Share/Storage"** Permissions for **70+** shares is **'Everyone,Full Control'** and are locked down by AD Security groups at **"NTFS/FS"** level. We want to add **same AD security groups**, as **"NTFS"** permissions to the "**Share/Storage"** permissions as well. 
There are many tools/scripts for changing NTFS permissions but have not found any free tool, which can replace "Share/Storage" level permissions recursively for existing shares. Tried '**SUBINACL','ICACLS','SETACL'** so far and no luck.Heard that it's tough to apply "Share/Storage" permissions recursively on file/folders. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Those three "utilities" modify NTFS permissions, they don't have any bearing on Share permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Used 'SUBINACL /share' to modify Share Permissions and it works like a charm.

Comment: Have you considered WHY you want to do this? This is contrary to Microsoft’s best practices. For the simple reason that using share permissions and NTFS permissions together causes confusion. Whoever made the share permissions “Everyone / Full Control” did it right.

Comment: 100% agreed with you, I have the same opinion and applied 'Everyone,Full Control' in the first place. It's mandatory company policy, where they need to keep same Share/NTFS permissions for some reason.

Comment: Thank you everyone again for the prompt replies, I really appreciate your inputs. Learned that I should not concern about files/subfolders for 'Share Level' Permissions. Only changing AD groups at top level share is more than enough for end user access perspective. Unlike NTFS permissions, where we should care that each/every file/subfolder underneath the parent share should have correct permissions for end user access.